# How to save image from camera/photo library into an array that is to be displayed in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage, uicollectionview

I realise that this question may be a little broad, but basically all I want to do is use image picker to select a photo by using a camera or within the photo library, and saving that photo to an array. I already know how to populate a collection view with images from assets folder. Just really how to save user images to an array. How do I name each image?

Also, it is preferable if the array could be a global one, so that these images can be accessed elsewhere.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simple use:

```
var myImages = [UIImage]()

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let yourPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
       myImages.append(yourPickedImage)
    }
   dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Edit:

Save Image to Disk:

```
func saveImage (image: UIImage, path: String ) -> Bool{
    let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    let result = jpgImageData!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true) 
    return result
}

func getDocumentsURL() -> NSURL {
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    return documentsURL
}

func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String 
    let fileURL = getDocumentsURL().URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    return fileURL.path!
}
```

How to store

```
let imagePath = fileInDocumentsDirectory(myImageName)
saveImage(yourPickedImage, path: imagePath)
```

Read

```
func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage? {
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    return image
}
```

Comment: Is it really that simple haha? Don't I need to use some form of saving data? Like writing it to file, something like that?

Comment: No. If you just need it into an array (and not persistent!) thats all you need.

Comment: I need it to be saved, so when the user comes back, their photos will be there

Comment: So you should store the images in your filesystem, and then store all imagePaths into NSUserDefaults() or CoreData.

Comment: How do I go about doing that process?

Comment: I see how this would save one image, but how does this append to an array?

Comment: Read something about "How to store persistent data in iOS" http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-data-persistence-and-sandboxing-on-ios--cms-25505 - And ask if you have a specific question.